# Hyperledger Indy iOS sdk can't import wallet

Tags: ios, hyperledger-indy

I am using Libindy 1.8.2 and trying to import my wallet for the recovery of my account after a successful export wallet. However, I am getting error from indy import method as:

**Error Domain** = IndyErrorDomain Code=114 "(null)" UserInfo={message=Error: IO error
 Caused by: No such file or directory (os error 2)
, indy_backtrace=}

In import wallet I am sending:

**importConfigJson** = {"path":"file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/D62D0B32-2FE4-4871-8B7D-ABFF84A574D1/Documents/walletData","key":"copens disuniting colossuses bunraku uppitynesses serviceablenesses brazenness lira bananas equipper adiabatically sorcery"}

**credentials** = {"key":"GqcA6WLrVAUUwVgTYAiekbMScmUMjwQM1Jb2KzuyeMbc"}

**withConfig** = {"id": "steward_wallet","storage_type":"default"}

When I a try to give relative path in my importConfig that is:

**path** = “/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/D62D0B32-2FE4-4871-8B7D-ABFF84A574D1/Documents/walletData”

My app crashes due to memory issues.
Can you please guide where I am making a mistake or any way around so I can import my wallet successfully. Thank you.

Comment: Dont add credentials on public forum bro

Comment: Don't worry, It's dummy credentials bro

Comment: I have resolved the crash. Dry run the flow from the start and problem, I have identified that I was exporting my wallet with encoding. simply remove the encoding method resolved my crash

Answer (score 0):

The second variant of `path` in `importConfigJson` seems correct. I suggest to try to import minimal (almost empty) wallet. It will allow to check a correlation between the memory issue and wallet size.